# Show last time user opened a shared workbook in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that is shared and can be opened by multiple users. I want to have a separate tab with all the users of the spreadsheet and their last time of opening.

Firstly is this possible? I've heard there are limitations with shared worksheets, I have alternative ideas around this but this way would be best.

I haven't tried anything yet so apologies for lack of code but if anyone can point me in the right direction it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: there is a function called application.username with that and the workbook open you could get it done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Verison 2: No ListObject**

This is a variation on my original answer. It seems that ListObjects may not be compatible with Shared workbooks, so this one just puts the data on a bare worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim nextRow As Integer

    Set sh = getSheet("TrackOpen")

    'Make the sheet if it doesnt already exist
    If sh Is Nothing Then
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With sh
            .Name = "TrackOpen"
            .Range("A1") = "User"
            .Range("B1") = "Timestamp"
            .Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        End With
    End If

    With sh
        nextRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        sh.Range("A" & nextRow) = Environ("Username")
        sh.Range("B" & nextRow) = Now()
    End With

    'Optional, uncomment to save
    'ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Function getSheet(sheetName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo uhoh
    Set getSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
    Exit Function
uhoh:
    Set getSheet = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Minor Edit: `nextRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` to  `nextRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. the sh is necessary because the sheet may not be active.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally possible.

Put this in the workbook module then manually run the Workbook_Open method once.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim objList As ListObject
    Dim listRow As listRow

    Set sh = getSheet("TrackOpen")

    'Make the sheet if it doesnt already exist
    If sh Is Nothing Then
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        sh.name = "TrackOpen"
    End If

    Set objList = getListObject("TBL_Logins")

    'Make the table if it doesn't already exist
    If objList Is Nothing Then
        Set objList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TrackOpen").ListObjects.Add
        With objList
            .name = "TBL_Logins"
            .ListColumns.Add
            .ListColumns(1).name = "User"
            .ListColumns(2).name = "Timestamp"
        End With
    End If

    Set listRow = objList.ListRows.Add
    With listRow
        .Range(1, objList.ListColumns("User").Index) = Environ("Username")
        .Range(1, objList.ListColumns("Timestamp").Index) = Now()
    End With

    'Optional, uncomment to save
    'ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Function getSheet(sheetName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo uhoh
    Set getSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
    Exit Function
uhoh:
    Set getSheet = Nothing
End Function

Private Function getListObject(listName As String) As ListObject
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim lst As ListObject
    On Error GoTo uhoh
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each lst In sh.ListObjects
            If lst.name = listName Then Set getListObject = lst: Exit Function
        Next lst
    Next sh
uhoh:
    Set getListObject = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for this! It definitely does the job I'm just wondering whether issues arise with regards to saving it as a shared workbook. I get an error message stating I can't save the workbook as shared (I'm wondering if this is just because its the old version of shared workbooks).

Comment: *I get an error message stating I can't save the workbook as shared* - Is this when you try to save it in the macro, i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Save`, or does it occur when saving manually?

Comment: Via the macro might not work in a shared workbook because of how Excel reconciles changes other users have made in a shared workbook.

Comment: I have to turn the shared feature off when editing macros, with the other macros i've made on the workbook this is ok when I save it again as macro enabled workbook. The issue arises when saving the workbook again as a shared workbook manually. The code works great and does exactly what I want I just wonder if theres a way around this.

Comment: Hmm, looks like tables (ListObject) are not supported in shared workbooks. This can be updated to populate the data on a standard sheet. Give me a few minutes and I'll post and alternate solution that doesn't use the ListObject. - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534